# Apache shows default page only for specific user

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have configured apache 2.4.18 on ubuntu through a virtualhost directive. This works as expected. However, while surfing from another wifi hotspot I do get the default apache page, stating that the page does not exist. Somehow the virtualhost directive does not work from that particular wifi network. How is this possible?

```
<VirtualHost 88.99.91.99:80>
     Servername www.globosapiens.net
```

Could it be, that somehow the network routes over another port? While using an online proxy service, the page shows up.

Comment: I think that we might need some more information. One place I would check first, though, is the IP address you are connecting to. If, for instance, you got the wrong IP from the DNS, you would get the default page. This can be especially tricky if your default page looks like a common default page on other servers. Then, maybe check that you are using the exact same domain name. I don't see the non-www. entry listed, though it might be down further. If all else fails, check the Apache logs.

Comment: Debug the request in Chrome when accessing the page and see what's in the 'host' request header. If it's mangled for some reason, it won't match your vhost and will go to the default one (which is what would happen is you accessed the server via its IP)